# Listen to a cassandra database with datastax

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, listener, datastax

How can I get a record from cassandra database every time that it is add using datastax for java? That is, how can I "listen" cassandra database? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it. Cassandra has [Change Data Capture](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html) functionality, but it's quite low level (and could depend on version of Cassandra), and it's not easy to use it. You can write your own implementation (pointers in link above), or use something like [this](https://github.com/carloscm/cassandra-commitlog-extract), but it's very old. And you'll need to handle deduplication yourself, as when you have RF > 1, every node will receive & write the data.