# Live Streaming using Spring Data Cassandra (reactive)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, server-sent-events, spring-data-cassandra

Is there a way to live stream data using spring-data-cassandra? Basically, I want to send data to client whenever there is a new addition to the database.

This is what I'm trying to do:-

```
@GetMapping(path = "mapping", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Mapping> getMapping() {
    Flux<Mapping> flux = reactiveMappingByExternalRepository.findAll();

    Flux<Long> durationFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    return Flux.zip(flux, durationFlux).map(Tuple2::getT1);
}
```

But it doesn't return once the stream is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, there's no live-streaming of real-time changes through the Cassandra driver. Although Cassandra has a CDC (Change Data Capture), it's quite low-level and you need to consume commit logs on the server. See [Listen to a cassandra database with datastax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896684/listen-to-a-cassandra-database-with-datastax) for further details.